# Remover plugin cocoapod do xcode

Tags: xcode

Eu instalei o plugin do Alamofire para realizar alguns testes. Agora eu gostaria de removê-lo para dar continuidade ao meu projeto.

Já retirei ele do arquivo Podfile e executei o comando:

> pod install

Abri o projeto novamente através do workspace e vi que os arquivos referentes ao Alamofire desapareceram, só que consigo dar um importe nele e chamar suas funções.

O que posso ter feito de errado?

Comment: Aparentemente ele fica guardando referência de pods que removemos, aconteceu comigo algumas vezes mas depois de alguns `builds` no projeto ele perde a referência de vez. Deve ser algo do cocoapods nas ultimas versões do Xcode.

Comment: ok, vou esperar alguns builds pra ver o que acontece